# In Google Docs, can I hide other users' cursor/selection?

Tags: google-docs

One of my coworkers left Google Docs open with everything selected, so the entire document is pink.

Can I turn off the user cursors/selection highlighting?

Comment: As a workaround, you could make a copy of the doc.  But if there is more than one sheet in the document it would be a real pain to copy all your data back into the original later...

Comment: Yeah I just resort to making a copy for viewing purposes when I need a "clean" view.

Answer (score 6):

If you switch from `Editing` mode to `Viewing` mode in a Google Doc, all the cursors (including yours) will disappear.  However, you have to switch back to `Editing` mode if you want to make changes.  There does not appear to be a `Viewing` mode for spreadsheets.

(I am unable to view other user's selections.  I only see their cursors.  Perhaps this feature has changed since May 2015.)

Comment: Um ... but how do you switch mode?

Comment: Top right corner, below the blue "share" button.  The default mode is "editing".  Click on "editing" to change the mode.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, at this time it's not possible.

**References**
[Chat and real-time collaboration](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494891?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

I found a Chrome extension that does this:
[Solo mode for Google Docs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/solo-mode-for-google-docs/jialeippmpkpbljcfhglaakoknfiojof?hl=en-US#:%7E:text=Solo%20mode%20for%20Google%20Docs&text=This%20extension%20allows%20you%20to,users%27%20comments%20and%20moving%20cursors.)